# Scope of names in Java

Tags: java

A friend told me that this a good example for learning Java scopes, but I don't understand it.

What is `a`? I am completely lost!

```
public class scopesexample {

    public static a a = new a<a>(a(new a()));

    public static class a<a> {
        a a;

        public a() {
            this.a = a(a(null));
        }

        public a(a a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public a a(a a) {
            return a;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "a";
        }
    }

    public static a a(a a) {
        return new a<a>(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( a );
        System.out.println( a( a ) );
        System.out.println( a.a );
        a<a> a = new a<a>(a(new a()));
        System.out.println(a.a( a ));
        System.out.println( a );
        System.out.println( a );
        System.out.println(a.class);
        System.out.println(a.getClass());
        System.out.println(a.a);
        System.out.println(a( a ));
        System.out.println(a( a ).a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so many a's. Anyway in this case first a is class type, second a is reference. Try to following naming conventions, that will eliminate lot of confusion.

Comment: I'm a professional Java developer and I am lost.  Don't try to understand code like this.

Comment: It's a good example to confuse people with scope. As a learning tool it should be considered harmful.

Comment: This code just seems intentionally confusing.

Comment: This demonstrates how scope works in a lot of cases, but I would say as a learning tool it is far from a "good example". It seems to be put together to intentionally obfuscate what it is attempting to teach.

Comment: I think whoever is teaching you scopes needs to learn naming convention first and probably code readability. 'a' is used for many things in this code, ranging from class name, generic name and attribute name.

Comment: This is very 'clever' code. That's not a compliment.

Comment: Not a great friend to tell you that this a good learning example.

Comment: Is it an obsfucated code ? or maybe intentionally modified not to be readable.

Comment: @user1329572: Is that what she thought you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My advice would be to ignore your friend.

He or she is either winding you up, or he or she has no idea about how students learn about scopes.

For a start, by using `a` as both a class, method and variable name, he has violated code style guidelines, and common sense.

The second problem is that he has added the problem of understanding namespaces to the problem of understanding scopes, which is unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: No it is not a comment.  It is an answer to the question.  In fact it is the only sensible answer to the question.

Comment: My friend always makes fun of me :/ Thank you for your time

Comment: @AliceBeatsy - send him to SO, and we'll make fun of him :-)